# Is it right/appropriate to say "double bag it?"

Tags: phrases, slang, questions

What one would say to get another (plastic) bag for carrying heavy groceries?

Is it right to tell the cashier "would you please double bag it?"

I am asking this question because when I tried to search the web for such phrase, I ended up with many results suggesting perverted, sexual connotations about condoms! Thus, I am a little worried about saying it in public or at stores.

Comment: This _is_ a fairly standard phrase (although it would usually be hyphenated: "**double-bag** it, please.") However, almost every phrase you can imagine has, at one time or another, been given a sexual/jokey connotation, and so the "wearing two condoms at once" meaning is also common.  As long as you use the phrase in the context of a grocery store, though, nobody will misunderstand you, and only sixth-grade boys will laugh.

Answer (score 5):

Double bag is a common saying.  It simply means to put one bagged item inside a second bag.  No one would ever blink or connotate it to something sexual unless you added some really directed context.

Comment: Never say *ever.*

Answer (score 0):

Well known environmentalist and broadcaster David Suzuki posed several years ago in front of his motorcycle, "naked except for a large hat covering his *suzuki*".

As the commentator then noted: this just shows that the sexual organs can be called absolutely anything pronounceable, and the meaning is always clear from context.

I believe the only context where *double-bag it* is not clear from context, is in an internet search.

;-)

Answer (score 0):

Double bagging at a grocery store is what it means, two bags to hold the weight of groceries put in them without tearing. The sexual double entendre is also a natural extension of meaning in a wide variety of contexts humans can (force) conjure. Further exemplifying them adding new context isn't worth our time here, I've learnt recently. Whenever you read an irrelevant or irreverent comment that gets past moderators, simply have a sense of humour about its content and don't presume any malintent.